# GlassFish 4 failing to deploy a dynamic web application in eclipse (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, ubuntu, glassfish

I am trying to configure a development environment for Java Web services in eclipse (in my Ubuntu machine) . I ahve configured the glassFish 4 server and integrated with eclipse. I think the configurations are fine beacuse I have run demo dynamic web project on the same glassfish server. The project which runs contains a Java Class and a JSP.

Here is the Java class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CatagoryFind {

       public List<String> getCatagory(){

       List<String> cats = new ArrayList<String>();
       cats.add("book");
        cats.add("movie");

        return cats;

       }

    }
```

and the JSP class does not contain any java. 
The above project works fine. But as soon as I try to make the class (see the below code) into a Web Service the glassFish server throws an error : " cannot Deploy TestApp, deploy is failing=Application with name [TestApp] is not deployed.

Here is what the TestApp contains.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class CatagoryFind {

       public List<String> getCatagory(){

       List<String> cats = new ArrayList<String>();
       cats.add("book");
        cats.add("movie");

        return cats;

       }

    }
```

Can anyone please suggest what could be wrong?

Comment: Is there a stack trace in `server.log`? Typically `server.log` is located in `glassfish/domains/domain1/logs`